# How to create a for loop that extracts each row of that matrix and prints it in a separate figure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, vector, matrix

I have a data file containing data for a matrix. I want to create a for loop that extracts each row of that matrix and prints it in a separate figure in MATLAB.

I have the following matrix

```
matdata =

   12.3000   18.3000   15.8000   19.9000
   43.6000   49.1000   28.4000   36.7000
   98.3000   88.4000   73.8000   63.2000
   33.2000   35.9000   44.5000   22.8000
```

And I have written the following code.

```
clear all
load matdata.dat
for x = 1: length (matdata)
for i = 1:length(matdata)
figure (i)
end
j = matdata(x,:)
plot (j)
end
```

But the problem is I end up with four plots of the same thing: all four are plots of the last row of the matrix.

How can I fix this?

Perhaps by extracting each row of a matrix and save it as a unique row vector?

and somehow following the order of 
    figure()
    plot()
    figure()
    plot()

Comment: the for loop creating figures is useless -- only the last figure has anything put inside.  Also you don't want to specify figure ids yourself, let MATLAB assign them.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are creating n figures (where n is the length of your matrix), but always plotting on the last one and leaving (n-1) empty.

Explaining your code step-by-step can help you figure out your problem:

Each time you enter the outermost for loop, you create a number of figures equal to the length of your matrix (in the innermost loop). Then you plot one row of the matrix.

I see two big problems with this approach:

First of all, you are relying on the fact that the smallest dimension of your matrix is the number of columns. Instead of using `length`, you should use the function `size`, if you are not sure of the dimension of your matrix. If you are, then you are fine.

Second, as I said, you've created n figures in total. The active one is always (in your case) the one with id equals to 4 (read your code, can you understand why is that so?)

The correct way to achieve what you want would be the following (untested!)

```
clear all
load matdata.dat
[num_rows, num_cols] = size(matdata); # Make sure I'm getting the number of rows
for x = 1: num_rows
  figure; #creates a new figure, let MATLAB deal with the index, as noticed by Ben Voigt
  j = matdata(x,:);
  plot (j);
end
```

Hope it helps.

Best regards

Comment: Thank you Ben Voigt and Catilho for helping me understand where I went wrong. I'm a bit new to programming and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps :

```
load matdata.dat;  
[x y] = size(matdata);
for i=1:x
    figure;
    plot(matdata(i,:));
end
```

You can also use **hold on** command as to see of all them in a chart :

```
clear all
load matdata.dat
[x y] = size(matdata);
figure;
for i=1:x
    plot(matdata(i,:));
    hold on;
end
```